# When are Android apps auto-updated?

Tags: google-play-store, application-autoupdate

In the Play Store, I have checked the box "Auto-update" for my application. However, although the app received a new version several hours ago, it is not being auto-updated on my phone.

What I'm wondering is how often are apps auto-updated (if at all)?

**Edit:** It's been one day and the app hasn't been auto-updated yet. I've tried letting the mobile charge to 100% overnight but it didn't help.

Comment: Usually they are updated when the phone is charging or with almost full battery and over wifi.

Comment: @NicolaBastianello Although I cannot discredit your information, can you please cite an official source? It is possible that you speak from experience, in which case, things are okay for me?

Comment: seems to be a duplicate but unanswered: [What time does Google Play update apps when it is set to auto-update?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/50350)

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't say it, I speak from experience with a Nexus 5. If I find any official source I will post an answer

Comment: Auto updates are not limited to WiFi-only by default. This setting must be selected in Google Play settings "Auto-update apps over Wi-Fi only"

Comment: @NicolaBastianello, I've tried your suggestion of charging the phone and giving wifi access but that didn't help unfortunately. I wish there was some documentation on when or under which conditions an app is going to be auto-updated.

Comment: There is some apps that needs approval first due to app permissions requirements changes so it needs manual update and accept new permissions in order to update

Comment: While this question is a few years old and I never really cared about when and how often my apps auto update (I assumed they did and I set it for all), developers like Microsoft (MS To Do, previously Wunderlist) have started the anti-pattern of nagging their users to manually get an update from the store, instead of checking if auto-update is enabled and ask themselves the question »why don't we roll out phased updates faster?«.

Answer (score 1):

If a user has auto-update enabled in the Google Play store, apps will be updated according to:

1. Developer preference.  Developers can specify that only a certain amount of users receive an update to an app, and then, if the update is successful, roll out the update to more users (either all at once, or slowly).
2. Region.  Sometimes specific updates are only for certain regions, so only users in certain geographic regions will get updates.
3. Device compatibility.  Only devices with hardware compatible with the update will receive it.
4. Android version compatibility.  Only devices using an Android version compatible with the app update will receive the update.
5. Apps requiring more permissions *should* prompt the user to accept new permissions before auto-updating.  I have heard about cases where this did not happen as expected, but have never experienced this myself.

Answer (score 0):

Check *Sync is enabled in settings & background Data is not restricted*

Then Check *app update is given to your Region*.
In Play Store, It is possible to distribute app by Region. For example, If A developer  given an Update to the US REGION, But you are staying in Some other countries(Even if you have downlaod US version) Play store will not update the app.